# Renaming a bunch of files but keeping the number part

Tags: rename

I have a bunch of files like this:

```
pic100.png
pig102.png
box103a.png
superb103b.png
px103c.png
rotor110 - new.png
ready1323 (yellow car).png
motorhome1036x red circle.png
...
```

so, you can notice that files may have 3 parts:

- a prefix that can be any string
- a number that may contain a suffix like "a", "b", etc.
- an optional ending, that is always a string and starts with a space, like " (yellow car)", " red circle", etc.

What I need is this: I want in one operation to:

- change the prefix to the one I want
- keep the number and the suffix (a, b, c...) if there's one
- get rid of the ending

using the first example, I may want to transform that in

```
object100.png
object102.png
object103a.png
object103b.png
object103c.png
object110.png
object1323.png
object1036x.png
```

how do I do that? As you see the only thing I am keeping is the number and the suffix "a, b, c" when there is one...

To make it simple, the command must operate in all files in a given directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A standard way to do this sort of thing is to use sed to generate the new file name:

```
ls | while read file; do
     new=$( echo $file | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([^ ]*\)[^.]*\(\..*\)*/object\1\2/' )
     mv "$file" "$new"
done
```

Before you do that, you should examine the commands to ensure they do what you wnat, and make a backup.

Comment: almost there, but files with space are not being processed...

Comment: @Digital Robot -- try it with double quotes (edited)

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, thanks!!!!!! that's now working perfectly. You are awesome! :D

Comment: If you are going to consider even a single space in filenames, then it is most likely worthwhile to consider multiple spaces... `new="$( echo "$file" | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([^ ]*\)[^.]*\(\..*\)*/object\1\2/' )"` .... The basic issue is that `$var` can easily cause problems with embedded whitespace. Using double-quotes solves this problem: `echo "$var"` or `var="a    b"` or `var="$(cat file)"`

Comment: There's never a need for quotes around $().  The operator itself serves as a quoting mechanism.