# How to bulk rename files/directories containing spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, files, directory, rename

How can you bulk rename many files and/or directories by replacing a
snippet `f o o` with `b a r` in the file/directory name?

For each suggested method, preferably answer the following questions.

- Is it possible to preview the result of the command before doing the
  actual renaming? How?
- Does the method work for prefixes only, for suffixes only, or does
  it work irrespectively?
- Does the renaming affect only directories, only files, or both
  directories and files?
- Will files/directories in sub-directories also be renamed?

#### Replacing a prefix, an example

To make the task a little more concrete, suppose that files like
`o l d prefix file 1.c`
`o l d prefix file 1.h`
`o l d prefix file 2.c`
`o l d prefix file 2.h`
should be renamed to
`n e w prefix file 1.c`
`n e w prefix file 1.h`
`n e w prefix file 2.c`
`n e w prefix file 2.h`

Suppose also that in the same directory there are (sub-)directories
named
`o l d prefix, dir 1 _`
`o l d prefix, dir 2 _`

Will those directories be renamed as well?

Can you tweak your method to rename directories only (and not files)?
Or to rename files only (and not directories)?

#### Replacing a suffix

Also consider renaming a *suffix* in files so that
`file 1, o l d suffix` and `file 2, o l d suffix` are renamed to
`file 1, n e w suffix` and `file 2, n e w suffix` respectively.

And similarly for directories. Rename
`dir 1., o l d suffix` and `dir 2., o l d suffix` to
`dir 1., n e w suffix` and `dir 2., n e w suffix` respectively.

#### Recommended methods?

What method(s) of renaming would you recommend?

#### Note

Note that *adding* a prefix or a suffix to a name is just a special
case of the more generic *replacing* of a prefix or a suffix,
namely the case for which the original prefix or a suffix happens to
be the empty string.
Analogously, the case of *removing* a prefix or a suffix is also a
special case of replacing a prefix or a suffix, namely the case for
which the new prefix or a suffix is the empty string.

#### More issues to consider

I am aware that there are other and more advanced issues to consider
when renaming files, such as adding or removing dates or sequence
numbers and/or topics like in the last five questions among the
references below.

I invite you to bring up any issue on renaming files/directories (or
symbolic links) and to construct a suitable example in your answer.

When writing an answer, don't feel that you have to answer *all* the
cases brought up here!
Feel free to focus on only *one* specific case (either one of the cases
above, or some other case of your choice), if you prefer to do so.

#### References

- [Let's compile a list of canonical Q&As](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2708)
- [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136/)
- [Bulk rename, change prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47367)
- [Rename files in the local folder adding a prefix or suffix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91493)
- [Renaming a bunch of files but keeping the number part](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35921)
- [Rename a list of files according to a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152656)
- [Remove character pattern at beginning and end of filenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/521846)
- [Rename multiple directories decrementing sequence number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57484)
- [Rename files by replacing today's date with yesterday's date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393168)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe I wouldn't quite agree that my focus is on file/directory names containing spaces. I am just attempting to cover the _general case_. And since file names in general may contain spaces, I want to have example file names that contain spaces. Nevertheless I just changed the title to contain the word "spaces". If this is how others perceive my question, then why not?

Comment: The bulkrename feature of ranger (need to install it) is probably the easiest way to do this task.

Comment: _bulkrename feature of ranger_ Interesting. I had never heard of it. Glad you tipped me. Thanks! :-) ~ * ~ Maybe not an obstacle, but I have to open vim to do that? (Not something I can do from the command-line ... ?) ~ * ~ Or maybe not? [This link](https://linuxconfig.org/manage-your-files-from-the-command-line-with-ranger) seems to say I can do it from the command line.

Comment: You are right Henke about ranger using vim for this operation. This is because vim allows the user to highlight and replace columns of text. Well worth trying anyway.

Comment: OK. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 0. Aiming for generic solutions <sup>1</sup>

For the convenience of my future self and other readers, I will focus
on *generic* solutions.

For simplicity I will assume that there are *no* quotation marks
– no double quotes (`"`) and no single quotes (`'`) –
in *any* file/directory name.
<sup>2</sup>

As a first example, I will show how to rename files with the pattern
`o l d prefix file *.*` to
`n e w prefix file *.*`,
thus renaming a prefix even if there are
spaces in the file names.

I am also interested in renaming directories, and will therefore
consider renaming the directories
`o l d prefix, dir 1 _` and `o l d prefix, dir 2 _` to
`n e w prefix, dir 1 _` and `n e w prefix, dir 2 _` respectively.

Secondly, I will show how to replace a suffix. As an example, the files
`file 1, o l d suffix` and `file 2, o l d suffix` are renamed to
`file 1, n e w suffix` and `file 2, n e w suffix` respectively.

Again, I want to see how this affects (or not affects) directories.
I will therefore also check to see whether the directories
`dir 1., o l d suffix` and `dir 2., o l d suffix` are renamed to
`dir 1., n e w suffix` and `dir 2., n e w suffix` respectively.
<sup>3</sup>

All of the above files and directories are available in a zip file:
[http://user.it.uu.se/~hesc0353/Files-&-dirs-SEunix-A690768.zip](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/Files-&-dirs-SEunix-A690768.zip).
<sup>4</sup>

*Note.*
The occurrence of `echo` in the solutions below means no renaming will
take place.
This is an established technique to *preview* the renaming before you
decide to go through with it.
Once the preview looks OK, just remove `echo` and run the command
again to perform the actual renaming.
<sup>5</sup>

#### 1. A generic solution using a for-loop

Renaming a *prefix* means replacing `o l d prefix` by `n e w prefix` :
<sup>6</sup>

```
for f in "o l d prefix"*; do\
 echo mv "$f" "n e w prefix""${f#o l d prefix}"; done
```

where I have chosen to search for files that start with `o l d pref`.

To rename a *suffix*, try :

```
for f in *"l d suffix"; do\
 echo mv "$f" "${f%o l d suffix}""n e w suffix"; done
```

> Does the renaming affect only directories, only files, or both
> directories and files?

– This method changes the names of *both* files and directories.
If this is not what you want, try the `find ... -type ... -exec`
method in the next section.

> Will files/directories in sub-directories also be renamed?

– No. Using one of the above commands as a template will not affect
files/directories in any sub-directories.
You will have to purposely tweak the method quite a bit if you want to
do that.
See for example the first solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48715885).

#### 2. A generic solution using `find ... -exec mv`

The `find ... -exec mv` method below gives you the option to rename
files *only* or directories *only* – through the `-type` flag.
It can also be tweaked to control how deep in the sub-directory tree
the command should search for files or directories – through the
`-maxdepth` flag.

##### Rename a prefix

The following command replaces `o l d prefix` by `n e w prefix`, but for
*directories only*.
Each file could be renamed in a separate sub-shell, but by having a
for-loop inside `-exec` (and closing `-exec` with `sh {} +` instead
of `{} \;`) the command runs more efficiently :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "o l d pr*" -exec sh -c\
 'for n; do echo mv "${n#./}" "n e w pre${n#./o l d pre}"; done' sh {} +
```

If you want to rename *only files*, simply use `-type f` instead of
`-type d` (easy to remember: `f` for files, `d` for directories).

##### Rename a suffix

Similarly, here is how to replace a *suffix* in a bulk of *files*:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*d suffix" -exec sh -c\
 'for n; do echo mv "$n" "${n%o l d suffix}n e w suffix"; done' sh {} +
```

##### Explanations

- `find .` Search in the current directory and its sub-directories.
- `-maxdepth 1` Do *not* search in any of the sub-directories.
- `-type f` Find files only (exclude directories).
- `-name "*d suffix"` Search only files that end with `d suffix`.
- `-exec sh -c '...'` Execute in sub-shells, allows command
  substitution, `$(...)`.
- `-exec sh -c 'for n; do mv ...' sh {} +` is more efficient than
  `-exec sh -c 'mv ...' {} \;` which otherwise does the same thing.
  <sup>7</sup>
- `{}` holds whatever `find` finds.
- `echo` outputs the result of the command – when you are happy with
  the outcome,
  remove `echo` and run the command again.
- `mv "sou rce" "dest in"` performs the actual renaming,
  replacing the old name `sou rce` with the new name `dest in`.
- `%` See [POSIX shells pattern filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536935).
- `done` ends the for-loop.
- `sh {} +` As already indicated, `sh {} +` closes the `-exec sh -c`
  clause.

##### Rename *both* files and directories

To deliberately rename *both* files and directories in one go,
just leave out `-type` :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "o l d pr*" -exec sh -c\
 'for n; do echo mv "${n#./}" "n e w pre${n#./o l d pre}"; done' sh {} +
```

> Will files/directories in sub-directories also be renamed?

The `-maxdepth 1` clause ensures that no files/directories in the
sub-directory tree will be affected.
If you deliberately want to rename a suffix for *all* files in *all*
sub-directories, here is an example :

```
find . -type f -name "*d suffix" -exec sh -c\
 'for n; do echo mv "$n" "${n%o l d suffix}n e w suffix"; done' sh {} +
```

*A word of warning.*
This method will *not* work for renaming a prefix in many different
sub-directories in one command.

#### 3. A solution using Perl rename

This section is devoted to those of you who have
[Perl rename by Larry Wall](https://gist.github.com/keymon/995151)
installed on your system (or know how to install it).
<sup>8</sup>

I like the prudent practice of renaming the `rename` Perl-script to
`prename` so as to avoid confusing it with the
[Linux rename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename).

> Does the method work for prefixes only, for suffixes only, or does
> it work irrespectively?

The fact that you don't need to bother whether you are renaming a
prefix or a suffix makes Perl rename easy to use.

For example, to replace `o l d prefix` with `n e w prefix`, do :

```
prename -n 's/o l d prefix/n e w prefix/' ./"o l d p"*
```

where the `-n` flag produces a *preview*.
Once the result is what you want, simply remove the `-n` flag and run
the command again.

> Does the renaming affect only directories, only files, or both
> directories and files?

As with the for-loop method of section 1, running `prename` will
rename *both* directories and files.

However, you can choose to rename only files (exclude directories) by
adding  `if -f` at the end of the rename string, like so :
<sup>9</sup>

```
prename -n 's/o l d prefix/n e w prefix/ if -f' ./"o l d p"*
```

If you want to rename only directories (exclude files) use  `if !-f` :

```
prename -n 's/o l d prefix/n e w prefix/ if !-f' ./"o l d p"*
```

> Will files/directories in sub-directories also be renamed?

I have found that – when using forward slash (`/`) as delimiter –
Perl rename alone will rename files/directories in the current working
directory only and not in any of the sub-directories.
If you use some other character as delimiter, you can actually
use `prename` to rename files/directories in the sub-directory tree.
The second solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48715885) is an example of such a rather
unorthodox practice.

A more normal practice would be to combine `find ... -execdir` with
`prename`.
For such an example, see
[this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366786).

#### 4. Other good alternatives for renaming files or directories

In case you don't like any of the above methods, consider using
`sed` or `awk` (possibly in combination with `xargs`).

#### References

- [How to install MSYS2 on Windows](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/)
- [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)
- [ASCII characters forbidden in file names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060)
- [POSIX shells pattern filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536935)
- [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)
- [Renaming files with Bash, removing prefix and suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12031081)
- [Renaming many directories at the deepest level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48715885)
- [A for-loop inside `find ... -exec` is optional but more efficient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423941)
- [Zip file containing the files and directories used in this answer](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/Files-&-dirs-SEunix-A690768.zip)
- [How to terminate the shell commands invoked by `-exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439638)
- [Perl rename.pl by Larry Wall](https://gist.github.com/keymon/995151)
- [Man page of the Linux rename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)
- [Use the flag `-n` to preview the outcome of `prename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521847)
- [Use `-f`, so that only regular files (not directories) will be
  renamed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238591)
- [Using a depth-first search to Perl rename files and directories]
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366786)
- [`sed`](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)
- [`awk`](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)
- [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

---

<sup>1</sup> When testing the commands/solutions provided in this
answer, I have neither used genuine Linux nor genuine Unix, but MSYS2
on Windows 10, which can be described as an emulated arch-Linux
running on Microsoft Windows. Of course, a viable alternative for
Windows users like myself would be to use
[Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).
I use MSYS2 because I find it convenient and easy to use.

<sup>2</sup> If in doubt, before considering any renaming whatsoever,
check the results of
the commands `ls *\"*` and `ls *\'*`.
Or better still: `find . -name '*"*'` and `find . -name "*'*"`.
To have quotation mark(s) in file/directory names is definitely to ask
for trouble, I think.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060) lists what
characters are forbidden in file/directory names.
– For Linux/Unix, there is only one forbidden character: forward slash
(`/`).

<sup>3</sup> I will *not* aim for a solution that changes both a prefix
and a suffix in one go, as asked for in the question
[Renaming files with Bash, removing prefix and suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12031081).
(If you need to rename both a prefix and a suffix, I would suggest
replacing one of them in one command, and then replace the other one
in another command.)

<sup>4</sup> I encourage the reader to download and unzip the zip file
to some (empty) directory, and then try out all the commands I provide
in this answer.

<sup>5</sup> For files and directories containing spaces, the preview
may look wrong because it is missing the surrounding double-quotes
(`"`).
Removing `echo` will still make the command run correctly.
(Don't take the preview too literally!)

<sup>6</sup> I use a backslash (`\`) to line-break long commands so
that you as a reader won't need to scroll horizontally.
When you construct a concrete example yourself, I recommend removing
the backslash and writing the whole command in just one line.

<sup>7</sup> To understand more about the difference between `{} +` and
`{} \;`, see for example
[How to terminate the shell commands invoked by `-exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439638) (and its references).

<sup>8</sup> Try typing `rename` or `prename` in your terminal (and hit
<kbd>Enter</kbd>).
If Perl rename is installed, expect to see
`Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]` or something
similar – where the word `perlexpr` is included.
If it is not installed, expect to see something like
`bash: prename: command not found`.
Another thing you could try is `which prename`.

<sup>9</sup> [This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238567#comment408962_238591) says the
`if -f` clause will also rename symbolic links.
It suggests using `if (-f && ! -l)` instead, if symlinks are not to
be renamed.